# Error: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, servlets

These are the classes implicated in the error (I'm not Using The Entreprise Java Beans):

```
@WebListener
public class EMF implements ServletContextListener {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "ldnr";

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "root");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "1234512345");
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        emf.close();
    }

    public static EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        if (emf == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Context is not initialized yet.");
        }

        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}

package fr.ldnr.daoImpl;
```

This is the class using the entity manager.

```
public abstract class DAOFactoryImpl implements DAOFactory {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public DAOFactoryImpl() {
        em = EMF.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void save(Object o) throws Exception {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(o);
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Object update(Object o) throws Exception {
        o = em.merge(o);
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Object find(Class myClass, long id) throws Exception {
        Object o = em.find(myClass, id);
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public List<Object> findAll(Class myClass) throws Exception {
        List<Object> objectsList = em.createQuery("select * from " + myClass.getClass().getSimpleName()).getResultList();
        return objectsList;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void delete(Object o) throws Exception {
        em.remove(o);
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Object queryObject(String query) throws Exception {
        Object o = em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public List<Object> queryObjects(String query) throws Exception {
        List<Object> objectsList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        return objectsList;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public long count(Class entityClass) throws Exception {
        Object o = em.createQuery("select count(*) from " + entityClass.getSimpleName());
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        return (Long) o;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }

}
```

So, the exception is: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Comment: So don't use getTransaction() as the message says, since that is a "resource local" transaction. You can get a JTA transaction using other means (e.g JNDI) http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/persistence.html#transaction_jta

Comment: Thank You. This was helpful to me. Finally I simply replace JTA with 'RESOURCE_LOCAL' in this code in the persistence.xml:<persistence-unit name="ldnr" transaction-type="JTA">

Comment: JTA would have worked just fine. The line `em.getTransaction().begin();` is completely redundant because you're using Container Managed Transactions (CMT). I expect that you're going to encounter other issues though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I simply replaced 'JTA' with 'RESOURCE_LOCAL' in this source code in the persistence.xml file: